# Averaging numerous values in a class

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class with a lot of parameters as it takes in all the columns in Excel, since this is the first step I usually do when building a macro. Then I started to think about how to actually accomplish what I'm trying to do and I think I just wasted a couple of hours of coding.

What I am trying to do is average each of the parameters inside the class as well as trying to get minimum and maximum values. There are about 100000 rows in these excel files.

My plan was to put everything into a collection and then I was thinking there was going to be some sort of averaging function or a min and max function for the collection parameter, or a way to send an array to a function that can calculate min or max.

What would be ideal:

```
Dim collectionOfRecords as new collection

for each row in sheet.rows
    Dim r as New RmmRecord

    call r.PopulateClass(row)
    collectionOfRecords.add r
next row
```

Then get the average from the collection somehow like this:

```
dim parameter1Average as double
parameter1Average = collectionOfRecords.Parameter1.Average '(ha, I wish)
```

OR:

```
parameter1average = GetAverageFromCollection(collectionOfRecords, Parameter1)


Public Function GetAverageFromCollection(records as Collection, parameterToAverage as something??)
    for each record in records
        sum = record.parameterToAverage + sum
    next record
    GetAverageFromCollection = sum / records.count
end function
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ummm - So what is the actual question? You'd be better served showing us real code you have written and where it's not working rather than telling us what you are attempting in psuedo-code with no real question at hand (other than implicitly saying, I can't get it to work). Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: There are already functions to calculate average/min/max.  Why not use those and leave the data where it is on the sheet?

Comment: It's a "how can I do this" sort of thing with the situation I am in. I want to be able to send a class type to a function instead of having to copy any paste a lot of code for each. I can post the entire code, I was just trying to simplify it here to show what I was trying to do. I was just trying to utilize code that I already wrote without having to go a different direction.

Comment: If I was writing this in .NET I would create a List (Of Type) and use linq to get these values. I am guessing there is no similar way to do this in vba.

Comment: Not sure regarding VBA functionality you are asking, but I'm pretty sure the same result could be achieved using ADO with SQL aggregate functions.